# Calculate a ratio from two MySQL SELECT statements

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a simple inventory table listing unique items, each record having one of a set of "Item_code". I would like to calculate the percentage of items sold in each Item_code group.

Easy enough to do in 3 steps in PHP, but I cannot figure out how to do it in one statement. Is it possible?

(edited to add the sum(Price) portion.)

1)

```
Select Item_code, count(*), sum(Price) as value1
                From Inventory 
              group 
                  by Item_Code
```

2)

```
Select Item_Code, count(*) , sum(Price) as value2
      from Inventory 
      WHERE Status like "Sold" 
       group 
          by Item_code
```

3) Percent sold = (2) / (1), for each Item_code

Percent value sold = Value2 / Value1

The result should be of the form:

Item Code  /  Number Listed / Number sold / Percentage / Value listed / Value Sold / Percent Value Sold

Comment: Here's a simple rule of thumb; A distinct clause will (almost) never appear in the same query as a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You're right. Removed the DISTINCT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` ignores `null`s. Thus, you can use a `case` expression to count the number of items sold without having to use a `where` clause, and from there on getting the percentage is easy:

```
SELECT   item_code, 
         COUNT(*) AS listed,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Sold' THEN 1 END) AS sold,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'Sold' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM     inventory
GROUP BY item_code
```

Comment: Works perfectly for what I asked. But I forgot to ask about sum(value) and can't seem to extend your approach to allow sum(). This works because CASE returns a True/False, so, COUNT(CASE()) counts up the 'trues', right?

Comment: @canadaroy `count` skips nulls. `case` returns whatever you want - in this case I return `1` for rows where `status='sold'`, and implicitly `null` for all the rest. You could do the same for `sum`, which also ignores `null`s: `sum(case status when 'sold' then value end)`.